# Exterior Faucet Replacement Anti Siphon Valve

Tags: plumbing

In my ignorance of how this valve is supposed to work, I over-tightened and sheared the valve. I am looking to replace the valve, but cannot seem to find any that are a similar style. The house was build in 2006, so I don't know if this style is no longer made or if I'm just using the wrong terms.

This is what the non-broken faucet looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6ijl.jpg

And here is my broken piece and presumably the part that I need another of: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOblu.jpg

Could anyone recommend how I might go about finding this part?

Comment: In the second photo you have a broken bleeder nut and a   replacement bleeder nut ? Is the old bleeder broken off in its threaded opening ?

Comment: Maybe bleeder nut is what I'm looking for. I  don't quite follow the question though, that is the broken piece that I was able to get out of the opening. I lost the other half however

Comment: Well  i am also confused because you say you need a new bleeder nut but you say you have, and show us a photo of, a new bleeder nut.   "*And here is my broken piece **and presumably the part that I need another of***" What does that mean ?  Perhaps you could add more information to your question so it clear and understandable. Have you done a web search for parts for my, (insert brand here,) outdoor anitfreeze silcock.

Comment: The 'new' bleeder nut is from a different faucet.

And the first photo that shows the whole faucet is from my neighbour's.

Comment: Gosh; if only there was a way for me to have known that information.

Comment: Finding the part may be possible if you know the maker of the anti freeze hose bib, sometimes call a sillcock.  **Try a dedicated plumbing supply store**. Is part of the old nut broke off inside the hose bib ?   It may be necessary to replace the hose bib.